# Does Redis allow using a list of doubles as a value? If not, what are my options for a key-value store other than Redis?

Tags: redis, key-value-store

The demo on http://try.redis.io/ inserts an integer with a command such as LPUSH test 1.0

Answer (score 3):

Scalar values in Redis are always strings. Yes, you'll see integers and floats in examples, but behind the scenes these are being stored as strings. Even operations like INCR read the value as a string, parse out the integer, increment it, and store it back as a string. If you want to store integers and floats and other datatypes in Redis you'll need to handle the conversions at the application level.